# Deploymenterror - Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: trigger

I have a new trigger to update summary fields from child object to parent object for a lookup relationship. I tested the trigger before trying to deploy. there is no issue. But I get the govener limit error the trigger is below. can you see any thing wrong here

```
trigger TPValuesOnContact on Training_Plan__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> ContactIds = new Set<Id>();
    List< Contact> updates = new List<Contact>();
    Training_Plan__c[] TPs = null;

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        TPs = Trigger.new;
    } else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        TPs = Trigger.old;
    }

    for (Training_Plan__c TP : TPs) {
        {
            if (TP.Traineeref__c != null)
                ContactIds.add(TP.Traineeref__c);
        }

        for (AggregateResult ar : [select Traineeref__c i,
                                   sum(Enrolled_STM_2015__c) stmtotal,
                                   Sum(Enrolled_Credit_2015__c) credittotal
                                   from Training_Plan__c
                                   where TraineeRef__c in :ContactIds
                                   group by TraineeRef__c]) {
            updates.add(new Contact(Id = (Id)ar.get('i'),
                                    X2015_Enrolled_Credit__c = (Decimal)ar.get('credittotal'),
                                    Enrolled_STM_2015_temp__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmtotal')));
        }
    }
    update updates;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
trigger TPValuesOnContact on Training_Plan__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> ContactIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> contactsForUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    Training_Plan__c[] TPs = null;

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        TPs = Trigger.new;
    } else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        TPs = Trigger.old;
    }

    for (Training_Plan__c TP : TPs) {
        if (TP.Traineeref__c != null) {
            ContactIds.add(TP.Traineeref__c);
        }
    }

    List<AggregateResult> agrResults =
        [SELECT Traineeref__c i,
                sum(Enrolled_STM_2015__c) stmtotal,
                sum(Enrolled_Credit_2015__c) credittotal
         FROM Training_Plan__c
         WHERE TraineeRef__c in :ContactIds
         GROUP BY TraineeRef__c];

    for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults) {
        contactsForUpdate.add(new Contact(  Id = (Id)ar.get('i'),
                                            X2015_Enrolled_Credit__c = (Decimal)ar.get('credittotal'),
                                            Enrolled_STM_2015_temp__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmtotal')));
    }
    if ( !contactsForUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update contactsForUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nomad, It works but still I get 4 errors when deploying, any it reduces no of errors. they all are related to Too many SOQL queries: 101

Comment: @JayWeera please post the code which lead to these errors.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the trigger in question, this just may be the trigger that set it over the limit. This appears to bulkified, I believe you need to review all your triggers and classes =s. The SOQL limit error is an aggregate number from all triggers.

There are a ton of answers to this question esp on here, just take a look around.  If you find a fishy trigger/class just create a new question and we can help..

It is an aggregate result, you cannot look necessarily by the triggers and classes that are getting the Too many SOQL errors, you must look through all of your triggers.  You may have to create utility classes for business logic that you do often

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this trigger is *almost* bulkified. The query is actually within the for loop, but due to some odd formatting of other braces it looks otherwise.

Look closely at:

`for (Training_Plan__c TP : TPs) {
        {
            if (TP.Traineeref__c != null)
                ContactIds.add(TP.Traineeref__c);
        }`

The query is right after this, inside the for loop. It looks like moving the query outside the loop without any other changes should solve this issue.